# How to implement Google Adsense in a Svelte/SvelteKit Project?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, adsense

I added the Script Tag with the Meta Tag inside the src/app.html, so its get loaded.

`<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-1250525441896834" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <meta name="google-adsense-account" content="ca-pub-1250525441896834">`

I also added a Ad Block i created a few days ago,
`<!-- Ad - KS - 1 --> <ins class="adsbygoogle bg-red-400" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1250525441896834" data-ad-slot="4037084447" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="true" />`

`<script> (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>`

Now there is a Block for my Ad on the Bottom of the Page, with Background Color Red, thanks to Tailwind.

Live Url: [https://www.kühlschrank.app](https://www.xn--khlschrank-9db.app)

When i give the Page to Adsense to connect my Webseite everything works fine, after a few days i get rejected because of:

Achten Sie darauf, dass Ihre Website den AdSense-Programmrichtlinien entspricht. Nachdem der Verstoß behoben wurde, können Sie eine Überprüfung Ihrer Website beantragen.
Von Google bereitgestellte Anzeigen auf Bildschirmen ohne Publisher-Content

Wir erlauben keine von Google bereitgestellten Anzeigen auf Bildschirmen,

```
ohne Inhalte oder mit minderwertigen Inhalten,
die sich im Aufbau befinden,
die für Benachrichtigungen, Navigation oder andere verhaltensbezogene Zwecke verwendet werden.
```

Weitere Informationen zu von Google bereitgestellten Anzeigen auf Bildschirmen ohne Publisher-Content

Weitere Informationen erhalten Sie in folgenden Artikeln:

```
Tipps zur Erstellung hochwertiger Websites (Teil 1) [auf Englisch]
Tipps zur Erstellung hochwertiger Websites (Teil 2) [auf Englisch]
Richtlinien für Webmaster
AdSense-Programmrichtlinien
Richtlinien und Einschränkungen von AdMob
```

Is my implimationen wrong ?
Google sends always i big list of possible reasons but no clear message with the real issue. :(

*ohne Inhalte oder mit minderwertigen Inhalten*
That should be one reason because, i have a login, but is it the only reason ?